# json data displays in console not in browser - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post

I have some json data I retrieve from php code by a jquery `$.post()` request. The format is json. But the data is not processed on my brower when the callback function is called

```
$.post(url_send, data_to_send, function(callback_data){
      var info = callback_data.info;
      console.log(callback_data.info);
      ...
});

callback_data = {"success":[{"id":some_number}],"info":"some_string"}
```

To debug, I noticed that : if I put in this code `console.log(callback_data);` the right json data displays in my console, but if I let `console.log(callback_data.info)`, the console displays `'undefined'`. Could someone explain that?

Edit : in my php I have $reply = array('success' => $ids,'info' => $info); echo json_encode($reply);

Comment: How and where are you displaying the data in your browser?

Comment: In fact, in the callback I construct some div with some_string as a content and finally I append it to the body

Comment: Uhm... if the callback_data is really as you describe above, there's no such thing as an "info" object for the console to log, thus "undefined"

Comment: are you sure your callback data has an 'info' attribute with a value?

Comment: sorry I have edited my post !!

Comment: what is the type of callback_data?

Comment: it is json_encoding of  $reply = array('success' => $ids,'info' => $info);

Comment: I mean if you do console.log(typeof(callback_data))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

callback_data will be in string format you have to convert it to json using eval to use it as an object.. once you do the eval you should have callback_data.info something like this

```
$.post(url_send, data_to_send, function(callback_data){
      callback_data = eval('(' + callback_data + ')');
      console.log(callback_data.info);
      ...
});
```

Comment: Great it worked, how can you explain that : echo json_encode($reply) doesn't return a json ?

Comment: eevn though your are trying to send json the data will only be sent in a string format and not in the json object format which should again be cast into the json object format on the javascript end

Comment: i do not know much on php but i dont think you can send any object in a specific json format.. the way you are doing now is just fine where in the string representation of json is being sent and then the string representation is converted back to json using eval

Answer (score 2):

The json returned by your php page probably doesn't contain a field named "info". So, when you try `callback_data.info`, since there's no info, it's undefined.

Comment: No since in my php I have $reply = array('success' => $ids,'information' => $information);
    echo json_encode($reply);

Comment: Yes.  Dave is pointing out that info and information are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The field is information, it shoud be: callback_data.information